# I am trying to retrieve the news feed for a particular type using the Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, feed

I want to retrieve the activity feed but of a certain type to eliminate extra processing in my code.

https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?limit=200&access_token=
I get all types of feed from the above URL.. is there a way to restrict it say just links or photos?

I tried adding `&type=link` but that doesn't help.
I don't mind using FQL if that is an option but can I make it return JSON rather than tables?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to fetch links posted by the user on his feed, there's a separate graph connection for that. It's the following:

https://graph.facebook.com/xxxxx/links

where xxxxx can be:

1. "me" to view your own links. (eg: https://graph.facebook.com/me/links)
2. your own profile id or your friend's id (eg: https://graph.facebook.com/60912312/links)
3. your own username or your friend's username (eg: https://graph.facebook.com/zuck/links)

Comment: Nope... I want to get the links posted by friends and not the user

Comment: You can get that too. Just replace "me" with friend's username or friend's ID. Edited the answer.

Comment: I want to get my activity feed, not just my posts or a particular friend's post.
https://graph.facebook.com/me/home
and then only retrieve type of posts that are links or photo or video not all